# Merge a table into an existing one

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I know how to `JOIN` two tables as create a new table out of the results, using `CREATE TABLE result_table AS ( SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB )`.

I forgot to include some columns from the `JOIN` in the `result_table`. Is it possible to merge some of columns from `tableA` into `result_table`? Is there a performance improvement over simply dropping and re-creating `result_table` again?

Answer (score 2):

You are better off dropping and recreating. Why ?

## ANALYSIS

Let's take the hypothetical example from your question

```
CREATE TABLE result_table AS ( SELECT * FROM tableA JOIN tableB );
```

This is literally a pure Cartesian Product.

Let's say `tableA` has `2,000` rows and `tableB` has `5,000`. A Cartesian product would result in `result_table` having`1,000,000` rows.

Now let's say you added the column `col_1` to `tableA`.

If you had to fill in tableA into result_table, what would the join look like ?

First, you would have to graft col_1 into `result_table`.

```
ALTER TABLE result_table ADD COLUMN col_1;
```

That's a pass through `1,000,000` (1 million) rows to inject a column.

Then, you have to perform a join of the ugliest kind

```
UPDATE result_table JOIN tableA
ON result_table.column_key_from_table JOIN tableA.column_key_from_table;
```

Remember I said joining 2,000 rows to 5,000 rows made `result_table` 1,000,000 rows ?

To perform the `UPDATE JOIN`, you would have to create a temp table with 2,000,000,000 rows. Yes, 2 billion rows (`1,000,000` times `2,000`). The temp table has to be created. Then, you have to perform pass through the 2 billion rows to populate the `col_1` column.

## CONCLUSION

I think you want to be finished working with the table so you can have time to raise a family, collect your pension, etc.. So, I'd go with the dropping and recreating the table.

Comment: Agreed to @RolandoMySQLDBA as Adding a new column will itself take time and then a update, so it is better to drop and create the table again.

Comment: This analysis is spot on in the general case. However, if the `tableA` has the FK the points to the PK in `tableB`, then `result_table` would only have as many rows as `tableA`. In that case, is it correct that there's not much of a difference between `UPDATE JOIN` and recreating the table?

Comment: You still have the issue of grafting in the missing columns, which will take some additional time, even if the JOIN results has the same number of rows. Still results in doing two steps (`ALTER table` and `UPDATE JOIN`). Drop and recreate is a cleaner approach because the appearance of the new column and its population is done in a single pass and single command.